# No Payment Methods when Authorize.net is enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I have being trying to use Authorize.net as a payment method for magento 1.9 site. The checkout page works great if I have paypal enabled. As soon as I change to Authroize.net the checkout page shows the No Payment Methods error.

With Paypal I can see the payment method at the checkout page, with Authorize.net the message No Payment Methods shows.

I have verified:

- Clearing the chache
- Globally enabled Authorize.net
- Modules enabled on System->Configuration->Advance
- Currency in Authorize.net is setup the same as the store currency
- Followed the instructions from http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/authorize-net-setup.html

UPDATE: I have found that we are using RicoNeitzel/PaymentFilter!!!

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: let's start with the basics...have you cleared cache? is auth.net enabled for the correct storeview? are you sure the Auth.net API credentials are correct? is the transaction key correct (try generating a new one)? if TestMode=YES, are you using the sandbox urls + sandbox credentials? do you have any payment-restriction extensions installed?

Comment: The cache has been cleared. The credentials are correct. I have no payment-restrictions extensions installed. Will be trying generating a new transaction key. And also will try to test the sandbox credentials.

Comment: Also, check your var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log files for any clues.

Comment: Created new Authroize.net credentials, I'm using live credentials. Still not showing up. Or any errors on system.log exception.log

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that we are using riconeitzel-paymentfilter extension. This will filter payment methods.

After disabling it from "System > Config > Sales > Checkout" >Payment Methods Filter,  changing Disable Payment Filter Extension to Yes I can see the Authorize.net payment method.